# Buttons on RelativeLayout cannot be clicked

Tags: android, onclick, overlay, onclicklistener, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` `saveCancelBar` that contains two buttons also contained in `RelativeLayouts`. `saveCancelBar` will only be displayed if the `EditText` `pageTitle` is clicked or in focus. For some reason, nothing happens when I click any of the buttons, and the `onClick` events (displaying a `Toast`, hiding the soft keyboard, and hiding the `EditText` cursor) are not triggered when I click them.
[image]

The buttons I'm referring to are the "Cancel" and "Save Title" and `saveCancelBar` is the layout that encloses the two. I did make sure to set `android:clickable="true"`. This is the XML code for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="missingPrefix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="app.travelers.activity.AddPhotoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/arrow_left"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="36dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:maxLength="64"
            android:privateImeOptions="nm"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="4sp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey700"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@color/grey700"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                android:text="List View"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chevron_circle_down"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/add_photo_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:minLines="0"
                    android:text="Add your first travel moment to your story"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/capture_photo_button"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/green_pill_thick">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/capture_photo_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="@string/camera"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/green500"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/capture_photo_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Capture Moment"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/green500"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/add_photo_button"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_pill_thick">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/add_photo_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="@string/photo"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/add_photo_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Add from Gallery"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_view_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="150dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">

            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!--Navbar-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photo_story_navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

            <!-- Take Photo Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_capture_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/green_pill_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_capture_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/camera"
                    android:textColor="@color/green500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_capture_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Capture"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/green500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Add from Gallery Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_pill"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/photo"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gallery"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Review button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_review_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/red_500_pill"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_review_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Review"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/red500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_review_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/angle_double_right"
                    android:textColor="@color/red500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/save_cancel_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/black_border_top">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/save_title_btn"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_pill"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/save_title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="Save Title"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#2196F3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cancel_title_btn"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_700_pill"
            android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cancel_title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#616161" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

To be specific, these are my onClick listeners:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pageTitle.getText().toString())) {
            pageTitle.clearFocus();
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            saveCancelBar.clearAnimation();
            saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(AddPhotoActivity.this, "Title is successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AddPhotoActivity.this, "Title is too short.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

});

cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pageTitle.clearFocus();
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        saveCancelBar.clearAnimation();
        saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

EDIT: I modified the if condition for `saveButton`'s `onClickListener` and added the `.show()` method to the toasts as per suggestions by @Nilesh and @Exigente05. I also added `pageTitle.clearFocus()`. The updates to the code managed to display the toasts and hide the EditText cursor, but `saveCancelBar` and the soft keyboard are still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most funny findings I am going to answer.**

You know what?

Everything is OK only you need to add `.show()` in the end of that two particular Toast.makeText.
See carefully, in line number 220 and 223 you forgot to call `.show()`

[image]

**Is not it funny?**

Another thing `pageTitle.getText() != null` will always be true. You need to check text length or emptyText to get accurate result.

To hide keyboard and clear focus change code inside saveButton.setOnClickListener

```
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pageTitle.getText() != null) {
//              pageTitle.clearFocus();
                View view = ClassName.this.getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                pageTitle.clearFocus();
                saveCancelBar.clearAnimation();
                saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Title is successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title is too short.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Also put same mechanism inside `cancelButton.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Adding the `.show()` method displayed the two toasts. However, the soft keyboard, EditText cursor, and `saveCancelBar` are still visible.

Answer (score 1):

**use this**

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pageTitle.getText().toString())) {
       getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
       saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(AddPhotoActivity.this, "Title is successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 } else {
        Toast.makeText(AddPhotoActivity.this, "Title is too Short.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

**instead of this**

```
if(pageTitle.getText() != null) {
       getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
       saveCancelBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       Toast.makeText(AddPhotoActivity.this, "Title is successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

} else {
       Toast.makeText(AddPhotoActivity.this, "Title is too short.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 }
```

Comment: if pageTitle refers to EditText, then pageTitle.getText() will never be null, right?
Then why not if block be executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pageTitle.getText() != null)
```

Have you checked your this condition?